# Is there a pipeline concept from within ScrapyD?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

Looking at the documentation for scrapy and scrapyD it appears the only way you can write the result of a scrape is to write the code in the pipeline of the spider itself. I am being told by my colleagues that there is an additional way whereby I can intercept the result of the scrape from within scrapyD!!

Has anyone heard of this and if so can someone shed some light on this for me please?

Thanks

[item exporters](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters)

[feed exports](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#)

[scrapyd config](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#example-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

Scrapyd is indeed a service that can be used to schedule crawling processes of your Scrapy application through JSON API. It also permits the integration of Scrapy with different frameworks such as Django, see [this guide](https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e) in case you are interested.

Here is the [documentation](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) of Scrapyd.

However if your doubt is about saving the result of your scraping, the standard way is to do so in the `pipelines.py` file of your Scrapy applicaiton.

An example:

```
class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #initialization of your pipeline, maybe connecting to a database or creating a file

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # specify here what it needs to be done with the scraping result of a single page
```

Remember to define which pipeline are you using in your Scrapy application `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy_application.pipelines.Pipeline': 100,
}
```

Source: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html